# Should getfacl be running constantly and is it normal for it to be using greater than 90% of available disk I/O?

Tags: centos, performance, permissions, hard-drive

I've recently been getting alerts from our server monitoring software about greater than 90% disk I/O utilisation.

I installed iotop and there are three instances of the following process showing up with very high IO:

```
% getfacl -R --absolute-names /var/www
```

Does this indicate a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that is not normal/expected behaviour. Is somebody running a script to find certain types of files that might be regarded as dangerous? e.g. setuid springs to mind. Who is the user who owns the getfacl process? Maybe somebody is trying to backup the ACL's

Comment: The owner of the process is root. I'll check with the server hosts to see if they are running any backups. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: A cron script had been setup to backup the ACL's every twenty minutes. I missed this as it was created by our server hosts. This only became a problem because the number of files on the server recently increased significantly.

Comment: @mrmike 20 minutes is extreme for data that almost never changes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton true, I'm not sure why it was setup to run that often. The script now runs once every 24 hours.